JS actions wired up to a custom button are not triggered - Ribbon Workbench
When the button is pressed, actions are not triggered.
In Ribbon Workbench, I have created a custom button and wired up 2 JS actions to it. When the button is pressed, none of actions are triggered. The web resources are in place and published.
Button properties Command properties Command properties
I have tried to add Mscrm.Enabled rule, but that did not work either.

Looks like publish issue. Go to solutions customizer and publish all customizations then republish the ribbon changes too. Should work. Otherwise, provide a snapshot of the function. Consider adding logger in the function and use Console to see if the function is failing anywhere

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can turn on the Command Checker to see where your custom button is going wrong.
Command Checker
To enable the Command Checker you need to add &ribbondebug=true to the URL. Once you do that, you'll see a new ribbon button called "Command Checker". If you click that it will open a side panel with all the buttons on this form; find your button and you can see its properties and any errors that occurred

